# ajax response (JSON) not calling function properly

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

For some reason the `success` function isn't being called in the following JavaScript code:

```
$.ajax({  
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost/hf_latest_desktop/st_pages/user_area/acc_buttons/pass_change/pass_change_ajax.php',
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(e){ 
                console.log(e);
                if(e.status == 'success'){
                    alert('your password has been changed!');
                }   
                if(e.status == 'error1'){
                    alert('please fill in all inputs!');
                }
                if(e.status == 'error2'){
                    alert('password incorrect!');
                }
                if(e.status == 'error3'){
                    alert('change failed!');
                } 
            } 
        });
```

php file ajax is calling:

```
    <?php session_start();
    session_cache_limiter('nocache');
    header('Expires: ' . gmdate('r', 0));
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    $status = 'error1'; //for sake of example
    ?>
    {'status':'<?php echo $status; ?>'}
```

Comment: Well, maybe the call fails for some reason? Can you try the `complete` callback?

Comment: tried 'complete: function(e){...'  with no luck either

Comment: Help me understand something. You say `success:` isn't getting called, but you also say that you're getting a console log, which appears to be in the `success:` callback. Where exactly is the call to console taking place?

Comment: i am not agetting anything from the success function, i can view the 'reponse' in firebug.

Answer (score 1):

Add the error handler to see what is being returned.

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   dataType: 'text/json',
   url: 'myUrl',
   success: function(data, status) { },
   error: function(data, status)
   {
      alert(data); // Print the response!
   }
});
```

Comment: logging to the console i get: from the error:  XMLHttpRequest { onreadystatechange=[xpconnect wrapped nsIDOMEventListener],  more...}

Comment: so im getting an error response i just dont know what it means!

Comment: Try just alerting the data you receive back. It should be the HTML you are receiving from the server.

Comment: Keep-Alive timeout=5, max=100
Connection Keep-Alive
Content-Type application/json

Comment: Try changing the data type to 'text/html' and see if that makes a difference.